# How to configure Bitbucket repository to ask password while checking out branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-checkout

I want that Bitbucket should ask for a password while doing git checkout

Is it possible in Bitbucket or overall in Git?

It's asking me my password while cloning the repository but not while checking out the branch in that repository

If you have any details about that please let me know

Comment: You cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

#### *You cant do it*

but you do use some "hacks" :

use `https` instead of `ssh`.
**Note:**, Users can pass it and store your password inside a credential manager

More about it:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage

To find out which credential manager you are using

```
git config -l | credential.helper
```

#### So what you can do? (Again, it can be bypassed easily)

You need to "disable" the "Git Credential Manager"
by removing the above entry in your config (usually in system level)

You can also add this line to your config

```
[core]
    askpass =
```

Answer (score 0):

[`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is purely a local command, which won't need to access the remote repository.

So it will not use a credential helper (HTTPS URL) or any SSH URL.
It will not request any login/password: it just locally access files and update working tree.

Once you have cloned a repository, any local operation is between you and... you.